# Z3 Java APIs for getting values of bit vectors

Tags: z3

I have written a program that automatically generates smt2 file and use Z3 Java APIs to parse the file, solve the constraints and get assignments for each constants.

Now I have some constraints in SMT2 file that are specified in bit-vector and would like to get values out of after SMT solving. What is the right Java APIs for getting the values from those bit-vectors.

I have tried model.getConstDecls() and use Z3_sort_kind to determine the type of each constant in a loop. It seems I cannot get any values from bit-vectors. I notice that parseSMTLIB2File has changed somehow. Here is a piece of my sample code:

```
FuncDecl c[] = model.getConstDecls();
for (int i=0;i<cons.length;i++){
    Z3_sort_kind sort = c[i].getRange().getSortKind();
    Expr expr = model.getConstInterp(c[i]);
    if (expr.isBV())
          //my own code to extract values from bit-vector.
}
```

It seems that model.getConstDecls() is not getting any bit-vectors.  I know there is a JavaExample to get model from bit-vector. However, I don't want to rewrite the program because it has quite large and has other things. It will be very time consuming.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not getting". When you print the model, does it contain assignments for those variables? If not, you're free to assume any value you like or you can enable model completion.

Comment: Sorry, it is working now. I mixed up with two different versions.